# Changing date formats in worksheets

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 and I want to somehow format the dates in those sheets without having to go cell by cell. My dates currently look like this:

```
10/1/2016  12:00:00 AM
```

I just want the dates to look like this:

```
10/1/2016
```

I am currently working with openpyxl but if their is not a way to achieve this within this package I can switch.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the dates in the same column or row? If so then you can select that column or row, right click, click on format cells and the pick the desired format.

Comment: No they are unfortunately in more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

You must format all the cells individually.

Comment: Alright I figured their was a way to find all datetimes in my worksheet and then change them to just date.